# Images unexpectedly not rendering in React Native tutorial

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am working on http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.25/docs/tutorial.html. My target is only to make it work on iPhone, not Android.

Near the beginning of tutorial it says "Press ⌘+R / Reload JS and the image should now render.", but my image does not render at all. The movie `title` and `year` do render, however.

The image does load in browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojab6.jpg

The code is at https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/tutorials/src/a5d5b3ea34c965475c2ba6bb035e21238e1eb9f3/mobile/react_native/official_tutorial/index.ios.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';


var MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA = [
  {title: 'Title', year: '2015', posters: {thumbnail: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojab6.jpg'}},
];

export default class official_tutorial extends Component {

    render() {
        var movie = MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA[0];
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
                source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
                style={styles.thumbnail}
            />
            <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{movie.title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.year}>{movie.year}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  rightContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  thumbnail: {
      width: 53,
      height: 81,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('official_tutorial', () => official_tutorial);
```

ios/official_tutorial/Info.pslist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>official_tutorial</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <!--See http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/ -->
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Why won't this image render in my xcode emulator?

Comment: It might not be rendering because XCode's default new project settings block all non-HTTPS network requests by default.

Comment: Check your Info.plist file for the `App Transport Security` field and set `Allows Arbitrary Loads` to `YES` to see if this is the case.

Comment: Or you can just change `http://` to `https://`, I just checked and imgur does support HTTPS requests for images.

Comment: (If this works, I'll add it as an answer)

Comment: how do I set the security field? I added my file above

Comment: Just change the `http://` in your URI to `https://` instead. Editing the `Info.plist` file is a last resort.

Comment: that worked, ty. you can make an answer

Comment: Done. :) Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default setting on a new XCode project is for all non-HTTPS requests to be blocked. Therefore, if you try to get an image through an HTTP URL in a newly created project, the image won't be loaded because the request for the image will be blocked by iOS.

The proper way to get around this is to only make HTTPS requests. Since you're getting an image from Imgur, which supports HTTPS, it's as simple as changing `http://` to `https://` in your URI.

If for some reason you really need to make a request to a server which only supports HTTP, you can edit the `Info.plist` file for your project in XCode. Specifically, under the "App Transport Security" entry, you need to set "Allows Arbitrary Loads" to `YES`. However, this is only a workaround for development and *should not be used in production*! You should only make requests to HTTPS servers from your app.